# How to know the license of a code generated by a GPL-licensed software?

Tags: license

I am using Glade to build my application whose license is GPL. I wonder what the license of the code generated by Glade is and if I can use it in a public application.

Does somebody know the answer or where to look at to retrieve this information ?

Comment: I think this is something that you should ask a lawyer. Also "public" is not a very descriptive attribute.

Comment: By public I meant an application doawnloadable by anybody on the internet or that I could sell.

Comment: Whether something is public/downloadable or not is not really relevant in this case. It's more about whether it's commercial/non-commercial, or, in the case of GPL, whether you are supplying the source code *with* your application, under the same terms. See this for more info: https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-lesser-general-public-license-v3-(lgpl-3) (The "library" license that Glade uses has been superseded by LGPL.) Anyway, I'd recommend asking on their forums as well.

Comment: Belongs on https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ - will depend on which version of GPL, and if Glade includes any of its own code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I wa looking for on https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Glade :

"Interfaces designed with glade may have any license, as they are not covered by the GPL's phrase 'a work based on the Program'.  " .